# pybot and robot command line

Tags: robotframework

I tried my best but I am not able to get an answer where I can find what are the difference between pybot and robot command line.

Is this two different options to achieve the same task i.e. executing robot test suites/cases? Or there is a special rule that says when to use **pybot** and when to use **robot** command line to run a robot test cases.

Please help me to understand this concept, an example will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pybot` was the old way to run robot. It was a simple shell script on linux, and a .bat file on python. There were different startup scripts for different robot interpreters: `pybot` (python), `jybot` (jython), `ipybot` (ipython).

In version 3.0 it was renamed to `robot`, based on enhancement request [2216](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2216)

There is no reason to use `pybot` anymore. It is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. The correct way to run tests is with `robot`.

Comment: "robot" file is a wrapped command line for python to execute robot with given parameters. For windows,robot.bat from c:\Python27\Scripts\robot.bat is just c:\python27\python.exe -m robot.run %*  so therefore if you have multiple python executables and need to be sure which Python interpreter to use, you can always run robot as:  <path to python>python -m robot.run <rest of robot arguments>

Comment: @Bryan I just came across rebot command. So like pybot rebot is also a  old way of running test in robot. I mean robot is enough to do all the task pybot and rebot were doing or there is specific purpose of using rebot.

Comment: @PrashantPathak: no, rebot is still a valid command. It's  for converting output.xml to log.html and report.html.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks a lot