# Integration of Robot framework Scripts with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I Am facing issues while running the Robot framework scripts in Jenkins,and executing scripts using "Execute Windows batch command" and my scripts in my local D:Drive.

Here is the executable Path:  C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;

Jenkins console output:

D:\Automation\Production House>pybot -d Adduser AddUserToRole.txt
'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Automation\Production House>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Comment: Did you try using python command instead of pybot? That's what I use in my Sublime Build Config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pybot and robot command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977934/pybot-and-robot-command-line)

Comment: Can u run pybot on your terminal ?